# Ejabberd xmpp Active user list

Tags: php, ios, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I'm writing a chat app for ios, i have a local installation of ejabberd server, the xmppframework on my xcode project and the xmpphp framework on a web server. I simply need to know how i can retrive the list of all active user in my server? How i can do? I'm already able to send message beetween two specific users, i'm able to register and delete user by php, but i can't find a piece of code that explain me how can i retrive the list of the online users... 
I have already setted a shared roster on the ejabberd server like this link explain:http://www.ejabberd.im/shared-roster-all (example 1)

Maybe my solution is XEP-0133 ? I have found this on documentation:

```
<iq from='bard@shakespeare.lit/globe'
id='get-active-users-1'
to='shakespeare.lit'
type='set'
xml:lang='en'>
 <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' 
       action='execute'
       node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-active-users'/>
</iq>
```

It seems to extract all the active users,anyway i don't know how i can send to the server this xml through php. So my questions are;

How i can retrive through php the list of the active users on my ejabberd server? 
How i can retrive the presence (if is online) o a specified user?

Answer (score 0):

do you want to retrieve data for your self or do you want to make it part of operations?

ejabberd has web interface with bunch of data, but I do not have one around to check.

When I need to do the adhoc query I look at session table. It holds all active sessions.
Where do you keep session? In mnesia?

Here is the link to web interface: http://www.ejabberd.im/files/doc/guide.html#htoc20

Comment: The data i have to retrive will be part of the operations of the app. In this chat i wanna see all the active user like all the other chat. Similar to facebook chat,skype chat ecc... I wanna retrive a list of username to place the classic green dot beside the name of the user...

Comment: isn't it part of roster info?

Comment: You described in your comment basic client functionality. Your buddy list is taken from roster. Then Users exchange presences to know who is 'green' and who offline. Probably facebook and google optimize it to avoid presence storms, but still this is the protocol. From what I understand, you want to aggregate session information and deliver it to client. You can do it, but it may be expensive and you need to implement your own mod.